# runOnUiThread() method in fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I use `runOnUiThread` at `fragment`. And how to do it in fragment?

Below is the code to do it in Activity

```
this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `Activity` context if you want to use `runOnUiThread()` inside fragment

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
  class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
    }


}
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
class DepositFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var rootView: View
    lateinit var mContext: Context

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        mContext = context
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        (mContext as Activity).runOnUiThread { 

        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deposit, container, false)
    }
}
```

Comment: onCreateView been always called on ui thread, this runOnUiThread is unnecessary

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin yes i know that

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that runOnUiThread method does.

1. It checks current thread
2. If current thread is main it executes the task immidiatly, otherwise it posing it to an activity handler

I assume, the best solution should be:

1. To create a new handler explicitly
2. Post task to a new handler

Smth like this:

```
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
...
handler.post {
...your task...
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#6919

Answer (score 0):

This question does not make any sense to me as already stated above that all calls in the fragment will always run on main or UI thread. No need to explicitly call @runOnUithread for that matter. Its required when you are updating View from the worker thread to switch the context to UI for updating Views.