# Unresolved reference: lang in this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Any ideas why "lang" is not recognized? I found code in kotlin in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355360/runonuithread-method-in-fragment-using-kotlin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runnable is class from lang package.

you should be import and use it.

```
import java.lang.Runnable


this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
})
```

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between my and your option but what actually happened, is now `Runnable` enough without `import java.lang.Runnable`

Comment: Yes, you can add Runnable without importing because it's present in android's java package and it is @FunctionalInterface.